# Plugin Admin Pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin

I'm trying to build my first WordPress plugin, and have admin menu labels already created using the add_menu_page() and content with a callable function in my functions.php file. For the life of me, I can't seem to add any javascript functions, or link to an external php page in the same plugin directory.

Has anyone else been able to do this?

Thanks!

Here's a code example. The code is a bit clunky, and I was wondering if there's a way to improve this/

```
function mt_sublevel_page() {
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Welcome', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<input type="button" value="Text Button" onclick="demo()" style="background-color:blue;">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<p class="test"></p>';
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'function demo() {var x = "Hello";document.getElementId("test").innerHTML=x;}';
    echo '<script>';
}
```

Comment: With regard to the js, google "admin_enqueue_scripts".  Not really sure what you mean by the second question about linking page contents to an external php file, but if I had to guess, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343761/use-multiple-files-in-wordpress-plugin-call-to-undefined-function-add-action

Comment: Share your code and we might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That wasn't very clear so I edited my question. I meant adding a link to an external file in the same directory that contains the page markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically how I load in a "mark-up" file for an admin page:

First of all, register your admin page function to the `admin_menu` hook:

```
// Standard PHP Structure:
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_admin_page' );

// Using a Class Based structure
add_action( 'admin_menu', [$this, 'register_admin_page'] );
```

And then define your admin page function:

```
// Standard PHP Structure
function register_admin_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'edit_posts', 'my-plugin', 'admin_markup', 'some-dashicon' );
}

// Class Based PHP Structure
public function register_admin_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'edit_posts', 'my-plugin', [$this, 'admin_markup'], 'some-dashicon' );
}
```

Now, you can define your `admin_markup` function:

```
function admin_markup(){
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/admin-markup.php'; 
}
```

This leads you to something like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_admin_page' );
function register_admin_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'edit_posts', 'my-plugin', 'admin_markup', 'some-dashicon' );
}

function admin_markup(){
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/admin-markup.php'; 
}
```

Now, inside your `admin-markup.php` file, you can make use of the [`admin_enqueue_scripts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) function to load in scripts and styles to style the page as you wish.

Comment: Hey, this is a great code. I'm running into a syntax error trying to load admin-markup.php though. Can that have html tags inside of it? @xhynk

Comment: You can absolutely have HTML markup in PHP, that's part of what PHP is for, to make outputting complex HTML easier and more semantic. If you're using an IDE it should tell you what syntax errors you have and what line they're occuring on. You can also enable [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to output it to the client while developing.